# Obtaining download speed from Linux CURL command

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have a code snippet from my Linux shell script where I'm trying to grab the average download speed of a sample file on the internet.

If I use the following code:

```
targetURL=https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file_example_JPG_1MB.jpg 2>/dev/null

curl -L $targetURL | head -n 1| cut -d $' ' -f2
```

I need the value that is under "Dload" (in the example output the value is 175. I will be storing the obtained value in a variable.

My output is:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0cut: stdin: Illegal byte sequence
  3 1018k    3 33834    0     0   175k      0  0:00:05 --:--:--  0:00:05  175k
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1362)
```

Comment: Try "curl -L $targetURL >& /tmp/curl-speed.log ".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

curl has a `-w`, `--write-out` option that should be able to provide you with the average download speed. See `man curl` for details (it says: `speed_download` The average download speed that curl measured for the complete download. Bytes per second.)

```
url='https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file_example_JPG_1MB.jpg'

if avg_speed=$(curl -qfsS -w '%{speed_download}' -o /dev/null --url "$url")
then
  echo "$avg_speed"
fi
```

The standard output from `curl` (average download speed in bytes/sec) is stored in a shell variable named `avg_speed`. For example, the result might be `179199`. You could use `numfmt --to=iec <<<"$avg_speed"` to print `175K`.

As the standard output is being used for the result of `%{speed_download}`, send the content of the transfer somewhere else (the null device in this case) with `-o`.

Comment: Perfect!  I wasn't aware of the shell variables for Curl. Thanks so much! 